# How do I get the left diagonal elements of a matrix/grid from a specific element?

Tags: python, list, matrix, grid, diagonal

I have an 8x8 grid of different numbers, and I want to get the elements of the diagonal that contains a given starting position. Here is an example

```
l = [[str(randint(1,9)) for i in range(8)] for n in range(8)]

>> [
[1 5 2 8 6 9 6 8]
[2 2 2 2 8 2 2 1]
[9 5 9 6 8 2 7 2]
[2 8 8 6 4 1 8 1]
[2 5 5 5 4 4 7 9]
[3 9 8 8 9 4 1 1]
[8 9 2 4 2 8 4 3]
[4 4 7 8 7 5 3 6]
]
```

How would I go about getting the left diagonal from the position x=4 and y=3 (so 4th list and 5th element in that list)? So The diagonal I would want would be [8,2,2,4,5,8,9,4].

I essentially asked this question yesterday, and a user was able to help me with getting the **right** diagonal with this code:

```
def rdiagonal(m, x, y):
   #x
   row = max((y - x, 0))
   #y
   col = max((x - y, 0))
   while row < len(m) and col < len(m[row]):
       yield m[row][col]
       row += 1
       col += 1
```

I tried to change that code to get the left diagonal also, but could not figure it out. What changes would I need to make to get the **left** diagonal?

Comment: What did you try, and how did it come up short?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that in the right diagonal, `i=j`, so you don't need two variables for `row` and `col`, as they'll always be equal along the main diagonal.

For the left one, notice that in this case `j=l-i`, where `l=length(arr)` is the length of your rows. Thus the following code will do:

```
def leftdiagonal(arr):
    k =[]
    dim = len(arr)-1
    for i in range(dim+1):
            k.append(arr[i][dim-i])
    return(k)
```

Comment: I'm sorry if it wasn't clear in my question, but I am looking for a way to find the left diagonal given a point on the array. That's what the row and col variables took into account. I wasn't just looking for the main left diagonal, I am looking for any diagonal given a point on the array. How could I achieve this?

Comment: @AltaafAckbar see my answer below. It works in general.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it like a graph on 2D plane. Row is the `y` and column is the `x`. However, python definition of row index increases downward, so 'y' is flipped. This means the origin is on upper left corner and 'y' increases as it goes down.

This means 2 things:

1. You can flip the rows of your list and you can use the function you already have
2. Or you can build a new function without touching the list. Logic is below.

'y' being flipped means the diagonal you want is essentially the following function

```
y = c - x
```

And finding `c` would allow you to find the diagonal. Naturally,

```
c = x + y
```

So to find the rightmost col or col with largest index,

```
rightmost_row = min(len(m)-1, c)
```

To find the lowest row, observe

```
x = c - y
```

So

```
lowest_row = c - rightmost_row
```

Then, you can navigate from top right to bottom left. Your current code moves from top left corner toward bottom right.

---

The code below gets you left diagonal.

```
def ldiagonal(m, x, y):
    #c
    c = x + y
    #x
    col = min((c, len(m)-1))
    #y
    row = c - col
    while col >= 0 and row < len(m[row]):
        yield m[row][col]
        col -= 1
        row += 1
```

Hope these can get you started.

Answer (score 0):

To start from any point:

```
def ldiagonal(m, x, y):
  while y >= 0 and x < len(m):
     yield m[x][y]
     x += 1
     y -= 1

print(list(ldiagonal(m, 0, 0))) #=> [1]
print(list(ldiagonal(m, 0, 7))) #=> [8, 2, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 4] # it's the main
print(list(ldiagonal(m, 4, 4))) #=> [4, 8, 2, 4]
print(list(ldiagonal(m, 7, 7))) #=> [6]
```